# Show divs based on dropdown-menu-option selected by user

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

The purpose with the code is to let user choose a number from a dropdown-menu and show corresponding divs. The startpoint of divs is always that all are hidden. The "user-selected-number" should be used by Javascript to decide how many divs to show. In this case as following:

Dropdown-value: 1 = show balance 0

Dropdown-value: 2 = show balance 0,1

Dropdown-value: 3 = show balance 0,1,2

Dropdown-value: 4 = show balance 0,1,2,3

**Observation:**

I suspect the problem is that the javavascript picks up only the option that is predefined as "selected" which would mean it does never take the user-selected-value for further processing.

The var_dump of $_POST shows correct result/printout, everytime user selects an option from the dropdown menu.

**Wanted behavour:**

The user should on the frontend be able to pick a value in dropdown between 1-4 and the corrensponding divs (see list above) should be made visible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Show divs based on dropdown</title>

  <style>
    .balance_0,
    .balance_1,
    .balance_2,
    .balance_3
     {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Form (Years-selector) -->

<form class="year-selector" method="post">

  <select class="dropdown_result" id="dropdown_result" name="selection">

    <option value="" selected="selected" hidden="hidden">Select amount of years to report...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>

  </select>

  <button type="submit" name="button">Send</button>

</form>

<!-- Divs -->

<div class="balance_0">Balance-0</div>
<div class="balance_1">Balance-1</div>
<div class="balance_2">Balance-2</div>
<div class="balance_3">Balance-3</div>

<pre>

<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>

<script>

// Extract selected dropdown menu option.
var amountOfBalanceColumnsToShow =
  document.getElementById("dropdown_result").selectedOptions[0].value;

// Show amount of balance divs based on above form.

if (amountOfBalanceColumnsToShow == 1) {
  var x = document.getElementById("balance_0");
    x.style.display = "block";
}

else if (amountOfBalanceColumnsToShow == 2) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
  var x = document.getElementById("balance_" + i);
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

else if (amountOfBalanceColumnsToShow == 3) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  var x = document.getElementById("balance_" + i);
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

else if (amountOfBalanceColumnsToShow == 4) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  var x = document.getElementById("balance_" + i);
    x.style.display = "block";
  }

}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added event.preventDefault so the form does not actually submit and refresh the page removing the client side event. Added a click event to the button and ran conditionals that sets the style attributes to block for the numbers selected.

I assume you want to show each numbers corresponding `amount` of their divs, so if 3 is selected show `balance_0, balance_1, balance_2` correct?

```js
let e = document.querySelector('#dropdown_result');

let send = document.querySelector('#button');
let one = document.querySelector('.balance_0');
let two = document.querySelector('.balance_1');
let three = document.querySelector('.balance_2');
let four = document.querySelector('.balance_3');
let selected;
  send.addEventListener('click', event => {    
    selected = Number(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
    if(selected === 1){
      one.style.display = "block";
      two.style.display = "none";
      three.style.display = "none";
      four.style.display = "none";
    }else if(selected === 2){
      one.style.display = "block";
      two.style.display = "block";
      three.style.display = "none";
      four.style.display = "none";
    }else if(selected === 3){
      one.style.display = "bloc";
      two.style.display = "block";
      three.style.display = "block";
      four.style.display = "none";
    }else if(selected === 4){
      one.style.display = "block";
      two.style.display = "block";
      three.style.display = "block";
      four.style.display = "block";
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

```css
.balance_0,
    .balance_1,
    .balance_2,
    .balance_3
     {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<form class="year-selector" method="post">

  <select class="dropdown_result" id="dropdown_result" name="selection">

    <option value="" selected="selected">Select amount of years to report...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>

  </select>

  <button type="submit" id="button" name="button">Send</button>

</form>

<!-- Divs -->

<div class="balance_0">Balance-0</div>
<div class="balance_1">Balance-1</div>
<div class="balance_2">Balance-2</div>
<div class="balance_3">Balance-3</div>
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct and the option variations of  dropdown (1,2,3,4) shows the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you should consider in your code.

- **You are using `button` with `type="submit"`** which causes to pages get reload each time and run the same script, so the value of `amountOfBalanceColumnsToShow` will always be the same (which is in your case it is your first option in the dropdown).
- **You are always just showing the blocks** in each particular condition and don't get any consideration of hiding unnecessary ones.
- **You are getting element by its `id`** where the balance `div`'s have classes instead of `id`'s.

To fix these things, you should first add an event listener to your submit button and prevent its default action, then get all the elements with balance `class` and after that with your conditions iterate through them and specify which one has to be shown and which one has to hidden.

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
// Extract selected dropdown menu option.
var element = document.getElementById("dropdown_result");
var submitButton = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
var balanceDivs = document.querySelectorAll("[class*='balance']");
var balanceDivsLength = balanceDivs.length;

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var amountOfBalanceColumnsToShow =
    element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;

  // Show amount of balance divs based on above form.

  if (amountOfBalanceColumnsToShow == 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < balanceDivsLength; i++) {
      if (balanceDivs[i].classList.contains("balance_0")) {
        balanceDivs[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        balanceDivs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  } else if (amountOfBalanceColumnsToShow == 2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < balanceDivsLength; i++) {
      if (
        balanceDivs[i].classList.contains("balance_0") ||
        balanceDivs[i].classList.contains("balance_1")
      ) {
        balanceDivs[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        balanceDivs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  } else if (amountOfBalanceColumnsToShow == 3) {
    for (var i = 0; i < balanceDivsLength; i++) {
      if (!balanceDivs[i].classList.contains("balance_3")) {
        balanceDivs[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        balanceDivs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  } else if (amountOfBalanceColumnsToShow == 4) {
    for (var i = 0; i < balanceDivsLength; i++) {
      balanceDivs[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.balance_0,
.balance_1,
.balance_2,
.balance_3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Form (Years-selector) -->

<form class="year-selector" method="post">

  <select class="dropdown_result" id="dropdown_result" name="selection">

    <option value="" selected="selected" hidden="hidden">Select amount of years to report...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>

  </select>

  <button type="submit" name="button">Send</button>

</form>

<!-- Divs -->

<div class="balance_0">Balance-0</div>
<div class="balance_1">Balance-1</div>
<div class="balance_2">Balance-2</div>
<div class="balance_3">Balance-3</div>
```